# "Collation wasn't advertised to any validator"

Tags: parachain

We are investigating fluctuating block production times, and something that caught my eyes in the logs were `Collation wasn't advertised to any validator`. What does this mean, exactly, and could it cause long block production times?

Comment: (The addition of the disputes mechanism has I believe temporarily reduced block times, but it might be fixed in v0.9.19.)

Comment: it looks like the para must have been assigned a core at this stage, and then the collator is issuing a discovery request to the validators associated with that core. Looking at the code the next step is moving to `advance_to_advertised` but it has not go that far: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/22967a4128702b12e438bb951aae32927b949dcd/node/network/collator-protocol/src/collator_side/mod.rs#L576

Answer (score 6):

This was partially only a logging issue, that logged this in the collator protocol in *some* occassions where it should not have logged the message.

The issue of fluctuating block times is a known issue and is planned to be fixed with the v0.9.19 release (at the time of writing), also see https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/4911